# References to All Defined Objects in a Python Interactive Session

Tags: python

Using `dir()` in a Python interactive interpreter session returns a list of names of defined objects as strings. For example, typing `dir()` after typing this code:

```
import math 
a = 4
b = math.sqrt(a)
```

yields this output

```
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'a', 'b', 'math']
```

`a`,`b` and `math` come as strings in this list. Is there a way to obtain a list of references instead a list of strings?

Comment: This isn't "all defined objects". "All objects bound to names in the `__main__` namespace". After all, it doesn't include `math.sqrt` or `None`, and those objects are defined. In fact, it's not even "All objects bound to…", it's really just "All names in…"; try `c = a`, and you'll get another entry, but there's not an additional defined object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since these are the globals, how about:

```
globals().values()
```

In Python 3, this is a view, not a list, so:

```
list(globals().values())
```

Comment: It's actually `locals()` that's equivalent to `dir()`, not `globals()`. Or, even better, `vars()` (because `vars(spam)` is also the equivalent to `dir(spam)`. Of course at the top level, locals and globals are the same thing, so it doesn't make too much difference…